# LOAD DATA IN ORACLE

Tags: oracle

Hi am trying to use load data in oracle. if am using

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '<>'
```

it is  throwing 
    SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 1.
    Expecting "(", found "LINES".

why it is happening .whether there is no LINES teminated by clause in oracle?

Answer (score 2):

I think `LINES TERMINATED` is not defined in ORACLE; check *Stream Record Format* from the ORACLE documentation:

> A file is in stream record format when the records are not specified
>   by size; instead SQL*Loader forms records by scanning for the record
>   terminator. Stream record format is the most flexible format, but
>   there can be a negative effect on performance. The specification of a
>   datafile to be interpreted as being in stream record format looks
>   similar to the following: INFILE datafile_name ["str
>   terminator_string"]

Example:

```
load data
infile 'example.dat'  "str '|\n'"
into table example
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
(col1 char(5),
 col2 char(7))

example.dat:
hello,world,|
james,bond,|
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm for more.

Comment: The LINES TERMINATED BY clause belongs to MySQL.

Comment: Ok, I retagged your question accordingly.

Comment: Oh, no, your answer is fine. I was just emphasising that it wasn't working for that precise reason.